# $K\subset L$ is finite implies $\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K \subset \mathcal O_L/\mathfrak{m}_L$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Given complete discrete valuation fields $K$ and $L$, finite extension $K\subset L$, corresponding d.v.r. $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathcal O_L$ with maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_K$ and $\mathfrak{m}_L$ is it true that $\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K \subset \mathcal O_L/\mathfrak{m}_L$ is a finite field extension. I can see that one is subset of another, but why should this extension be finite?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show the following statement from which the result follows

> If $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\mathcal O_L^\times$ are elements such that $\bar\alpha_1,\dots,\bar\alpha_n\in\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak m_L$ are linearly independent over $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m_K$, then $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $K$.

Do this as follows:

1. Suppose $\bar\alpha_1,\dots,\bar\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m_K$, and suppose you have an equation $c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n=0$ in $L$ with $c_i\in K$.
2. Scale by the $c_i$ with largest absolute value so that, without loss of generality, you can assume some $c_i$ has absolute value $1$ and the rest $\le1$.
3. Consider the equation modulo $\mathfrak m_L$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that is very nice. Another question: if I know that $\mathcal O_L\cong\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{[L:K]} \mathcal O_K $ is there a more straightforward argument? Seems like finiteness of extension must follow immediately from this fact, however I am not sure.

Comment: Oh yeah if you take a uniformizer $\pi$ for $K$, the equality of $\mathcal O_K$-modules you've given implies the isomorphism $L=\mathcal O_L[1/\pi]\simeq\oplus_{i=1}^{[L:K]}\mathcal O_K[1/\pi]=\oplus_{i=1}^{[L:K]}K$ of $K$-modules